# dspace import metadata acknowledges changes doesn't apply them

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, dspace

Whenever I try to import metadata to my DSpace repository, the same way I've always done it before, something strange happens.

First of all DSpace allows me to upload the correctly formed CSV files, then it actually shows me what changes where detected ("Pending changes are listed below for review") and asks me to review them.

Finally when I accept the changes I get a message telling me "No changes were detected".

Could somebody shed some light?

Things I have tried to no success:

- Restarting the Tomcat server
- Trying to upload different CSV files
- Using different users

Thanks a lot

**UPDATE 03/10/2012**

I have tried the commandline import tool and now I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Collection 105 has no default item READ policies
    at org.dspace.content.Item.inheritCollectionDefaultPolicies(Item.java:2189)
    at org.dspace.content.InstallItem.finishItem(InstallItem.java:220)
    at org.dspace.content.InstallItem.installItem(InstallItem.java:83)
    at org.dspace.content.InstallItem.installItem(InstallItem.java:42)
    at org.dspace.app.bulkedit.MetadataImport.runImport(MetadataImport.java:239)
    at org.dspace.app.bulkedit.MetadataImport.main(MetadataImport.java:1060)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Any clues?

Comment: I've nailed it. That last bit took me to the permissions area where all I need to do was add the "DEFAULT_ITEM_READ" permission to the group "Administrator".

Here are some places that helped me deal with the problem:

Comment: [http://www.dspace.org/1_6_0Documentation/ch08.html](http://www.dspace.org/1_6_0Documentation/ch08.html)

Comment: [http://dspace.2283337.n4.nabble.com/Dspace-tech-Internal-System-Error-after-granting-licence-td3288317.html](http://dspace.2283337.n4.nabble.com/Dspace-tech-Internal-System-Error-after-granting-licence-td3288317.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that last update lead me to google the error which quickly pointed me to: http://dspace.2283337.n4.nabble.com/Dspace-tech-Internal-System-Error-after-granting-licence-td3288317.html. Then it was just a metter of checking permissions for the collection, where I realized that DEFAULT_BITSTREAM_READ was set twice, giving the impression of DEFAULT_ITEM_READ also being enabled. After granting the DEFAULT_ITEM_READ permission to the "Administrator" group it was fixed.

Comment: Hey John can I have your email address ? I wanted to discuss regarding Dspace. Or may be you can email me on "hardik.dspace at aol dot in"